# How do I send EOF to Cygwin console?

Tags: keyboard, cygwin, keyboard-shortcuts

In cygwin console, I want to send EOF by keyboard.
I tried Ctrl + D, Ctrl + Z, and others, then they went wrong.

Example)

```
$ php
<?php
echo "test\n";
{ Push Ctrl + D, then nothing happens. }

$ php
<?php
echo "test\n";
{ Push Ctrl + Z, then "Stopped" appears and echo above doesn't invoked. }
```

Is there a way to send EOF to Cygwin console?

Answer (score -1):

`Ctrl-D` sends `EOF`.  The reason your first attempt didn't work is that your code was missing the closing brace.  Try the following instead:

```
$ php
<?php
echo "test\n";
?>
```

*then* press `Ctrl-D`, and you will see `test` printed to console.

Comment: I think it doesn't need the closing brace on php script. As you suggest, I tried to write code with closing brace and I press Ctrl-D, then nothing happens.

Comment: Which console are you using?  I tested this in mintty.